# Forwarding domain Links are not working

Tags: .htaccess

I have two domains abc.com & xyz.com and I want to run same site on both domains

```
i.e visitor visit abc.com & sees abc.com & address bar= abc.com
now visitor visit xyz.com & sees abc.com & address bar= xyz.com
with all link working like xyz.com/products same as abc.com/products
```

what I want to do to correct links I successfully forward my domain (xyz.com to abc.com) via godaddy, now visitor visit xyz.com but see content from abc.com and addressbar shows xyz.com problem is on clicking the link xyz.com/products addressbar becomes abc.com/products

please help me & i want to do this via .htaccess file

Comment: Are the links on html page relative or absolute?

Comment: I think absolute but not sure,
is there any problem